# Toggle linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls

I need to create a complex toggle button (rtl checkbox).

I know that LinearLayout can be clickable, and I saw the following [example](http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/)

Can I do it through XML only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinearLayout can be clickable but not not checkable.
To get RTL toggle view I did the following:

1. I created a nine-path images to pressed, checked and default state.
2. Created a selector:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_off"/>
```

3.Created a class that extends Button and Implements Checkable:

```
public class MyCheckbox extends Button implements Checkable {

private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_checked};
private boolean mIsChecked = false;

public MyCheckbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public MyCheckbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyCheckbox(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return mIsChecked;
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
    mIsChecked = isChecked;
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!mIsChecked);
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    toggle();
    return super.performClick();
}

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
    if (isChecked()) {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
    }
    return drawableState;
}

}
```

In the same way it can be implemented on a clickable LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes and other views should be directly swapped when using rtl locales.
If you want to make sure you are compliant with RTL languages use the new "start" & "end" params included in JellyBean (marginStart & marginEnd instead of marginLeft/Right & marginRight/Left). Although if you need that behavior for previous versions you might need other tricks.
Note that TextView's will already move completely to the other side of the box: make sure you don't use a lot of WRAP_CONTENT in that case, it may result in misalignments.

Comment: I need to support lower versions and the background contains an image (nine patch) on the right side and text must be on the left.

Comment: The my approach would be using a TextView and setting the drawable programmatically in regards to the language. textView.setCompoundDrawables(rtlLanguage?null:drawable, null, rtlLanguage?drawable:null, null);